# kubuntu 13.04 - run applications minimized at startup

Tags: 13.04, kubuntu, startup, kde

I have ubuntu 13.04 and kde 4.11.

I'd like to start *thunderbird*  *goldendict* and *calibre* at startup but they have to minimized.

I have tried `kstart` but it doesn't work well I guess.

I have already set them up to run at startup from System Administration/Startup but at this moment they run at startup in normal mode.

How can I do that? If there is no way to do that from kde settings I could also use a script that will run at startup.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to achive that with [KWin Rules Window Matching](http://userbase.kde.org/KWin_Rules_Window_Matching).

### Example Calibre application.

**1)** Make sure to disable the *"splash screen on startup*" in calibre

- Open Calibre and go to **Preferences > Look and Feel > Main Interface**

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Uncheck **"Show splash screen on startup"** , then click and **"Apply"**

  ---

**2)** Go to **System Settings > Window Behavior > Window Rules**

[image]

[image]

---

**3)** Creating the rule.

- Click in **"New"** a new window cames up and fill the *Description*. eg: **Calibre**.
- Click in **"Detect Window Properties"**, the cursor will be a **"Cross"** and with the cross click in the Calibre Window.

[image]

- A new window will appear (With the calibre window information), check **"Secondary class name"** then **OK**.

[image]

- Go to the **Size & Position** tab and check **Minimized** , **Apply Initially** and **Yes**.

[image]

- Click **OK** then **Apply**

  ---

**4)** Add Calibre to startup.

- Go to **System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart** then click in **Add Program**

[image]

[image]

- Search for *Calibre* in the *Office Category*, then click **OK**, then Click **OK** again in the *Properties for calibre.desktop window*

---

Finally you can Logout and Login or Restart you computer to test **"Calibre minimized at startup"**.

It should look like this:

[image]

Calibre will start minimized in the **Task Manager**.

**NOTE**: Please change the rule for matching anything according to your needs. This is just an example.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

It is much simpler with KDE 4:

1. Just right click the desired target program's window titlebar
2. Click Additional Actions
3. Click Special settings for this program
4. Select "Size and Position" tab (2nd tab from the left)
5. Activate the checkbox "Minimized", select when to minimize on the dropdown field, select "yes" from the radiobutton.

Done